# how do I remove partially-disintegrated sediment/tiny-bones from stock?

Tags: beef, stock, broth, bones, simmer

I have just finished my first batch of bone broth, and have removed all of the bones I could find.  I noticed that there are some smaller pieces, as well as "grit" from disintegrated bones, which seems to be from the handiwork of my vinegar leaching minerals from the bones.

I am wondering what people normally do when dealing with these very tiny gritty pieces, as well as pieces that could have been hard to miss that are still bones/larger grit.  I went through with a strainer, but the issue is that the marrow is also strained so I have to pick through.  Currently it is very hot, so I am waiting for it to cool down before I pick through it more.

My questions are

1. How do people get rid of the very tiny pieces of bone/tiny-grit from the bones.
2. Is there an issue with eating the grit and such?  It seems that it would be disintegrated with more time, so there shouldn't be an issue.  What about small bone pieces?  It seems that with the long simmer the bones are a lot softer, so there wouldn't be splintering, but it's probably still a possibility.

Any help would be appreciated on how to deal with/ work with tiny-bones and grit, thank you!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straining *might* work, but you may need to use a process known as "decanting":

- Let the stock sit until any sediment falls to the bottom.
- Remove the good liquid, avoiding the sediment at the bottom.

You can do this a few ways :

- Use something to scoop the good liquid off the top
- Use a hose to siphon off the good liquid until just before you get to the sediment
- Carefully pour off the good liquid, stopping when you notice the sediment rising to the top

This is more difficult with stock, as when it cools, the gelatin will start to thicken making pouring a bit tricker ... but it means one more potential method:

- Let the stock set up, then remove it as a block from the container (you may need to set the whole thing in hot water to get it to release; sometimes a hot-water spray or wrapping it in damp hot towels is enough).  Slice off and remove the sediment layer.  Put what's left back in the container.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the information on decanting.  I actually let it sit for awhile, scooped out what I needed, poured the liquid out and noticed a pile of sediment on the bottom, which I got rid of.  Right now the stock is in a half gallon glass jar, with the remainder in a bowl.  I will try to continue with this method and remove the sediment by letting it settle.  I did notice that I scooped some sediment up when trying to scoop marrow, so next time I think I will try to avoid scooping close to the bottom which should avoid any sediment getting in my strainer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Straining using cheesecloth would be ideal. You can do it a few times or through as many layers as you want to get all the particles out.

There isn't a problem with eating bone particles, but texture-wise these aren't desirable.

Comment: The way I read it, the OP wants to remove the bone particles but leave in all the other stuff that would be strained if using cheesecloth.

Comment: Thanks.  I have a cheesecloth, but I wanted to make sure I got all of the good marrow and such as well, which seemed to be a pain with lots of sediment.  This was shown when straining the marrow and sometimes getting grit.  Thank you for letting me know about the particles, I figured they are small/brittle enough that I wouldn't be hurt by eating them, as long as I don't get any decent sized bits that I missed.  @rumtscho that is correct, bones/grit/sediment is what I want removed, unless it isn't a huge deal, but I rather not have to worry about biting into bones and such and enjoy my stock.